# Position Issue for dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am styling a dropdown menu that uses jQuery .hover() to display a hidden set of list items, when the hover is activated the hidden list items moves the parent list item out of position.

#### The CSS

```
mainNav {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    width: 50 % ;
    float: left;
}

mainNav li {
    float: left;
    list - style: none;
}

mainNav ul {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    z - index: 0;
}

mainNav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px 13px 15px;
    border: none;
    color: #777;
    float:left;
}

.drop-list{
    display:none;
    float:none;
    position:relative!important;
    z-index:100!important;
}

.drop-list li{
    float:none!important;
    position:relative!important;
    z-index:100!important;
}
```

#### The html

```
<div id="mainNav">

    <ul>
        <li class="drop-item"><a href="">Home</a>
            <ul class="drop-list">
                <li>SubNav</li>
                <li>SubNav</li>
                <li>SubNav</li>
                <li>SubNav</li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="drop-item"><a href="">Nav</a></li>

        <li class="drop-item"><a href="">Nav</a></li>

        <li class="drop-item"><a href="">Nav</a></li>  
   </ul>  
</div>
```

#### jQuery

```
$("li.drop-item").hover(function () {
    $(this).children('.drop-list').show();
    $(this).children('.drop-list').stop();
    $(this).children('.drop-list').animate({
        opacity: 1.0
    }, 200);
}, function () {
    $(this).children('.drop-list').stop();
    $(this).children('.drop-list').animate({
        opacity: 0.0
    }, 400, function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

again I am styling a dropdown menu that uses jQuery .hover() to display a hidden set of list items, when the hover is activated the hidden list items moves the parent list item out of position.  The child list item should come to the front of the content without effecting any other elements.

#### JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/JaySm/AXDdN/

Comment: please create a fiddle.

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9BNF/) of his problem

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JaySm/AXDdN/

Comment: You don't need jQuery, or even Javascript at all, for this. Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/vWDvy/

Comment: Here's a quick example without javascript but with opacity transitions and using your code: http://jsfiddle.net/SRafC/

Comment: @Joe that's awesome, tutorials on this subject are beyound useless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Position the submenu absolutely:

```
.drop-list{
    position:absolute;
}
```

To elaborate:

By setting `position:relative`, you can position the element as you like. However, by the standards it will still be displayed in the flow of elements as if it was not positioned. In other words, a gap will remain in its original space. This will cause surrounding elements to be moved about, such as in OPs menu.

Setting `position:absolute` will position the element. As if it's taken off the canvas and put on a layer above (or below). Its original space will be truncated, and surrounding elements will be unaffected. This will solve OPs problem.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please comment to say why. From my own perspective though, Anders, I placed OP's code and yours in a Fiddle and this doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Make sure you remove the previously assigned `position:relative!important;` before you add the above.

Comment: This is the right answer: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9BNF/1/) to show the start of the fix. More [stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427002/css-dropdown-float-on-top) questions about this.

Comment: Turns out my Fiddle was messed up. Added to the Fiddle in the OP and this does have an effect. However, the submenu appears on top of the menu, which isn't really fully working. Solves the original question of not moving, however, so +1.

Comment: Glad it solved your problem @Jay.Smyth! As the answer got some downvotes I elaborated the answer. Anyone may feel free to _comment_ if you do not agree...